# Proving that this set is open in a metric space.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A$ be a nonempty set in the metric space $(X,d)$ and, for $\epsilon>0$, define

$$A_\epsilon = \{x\in X: d(x,A) < \epsilon\}$$.

Then I want to prove that $A_\epsilon$ is open in $X$.

So what I have tried so far is that, well I want to prove that a set is open so I take $x \in A_\epsilon $, then we have to show that $B_{\epsilon_{1}} \subset A_\epsilon$ for a fix $\epsilon$, and since it is clear that $A_\frac{\epsilon}{2}\subset A_\epsilon$ we take  $\epsilon_{1}=\epsilon-d(x,A)$ and we pick $z \in B_{\frac{\epsilon_{1}}{2}} $ and we observe the following:

> I think I got it, $$d(z,A)<d(z,x)+d(x,A)<\epsilon_{1}+d(x,A)=\epsilon-d(x,A)+d(x,A)=\epsilon$$ **Am I right?, and Is the triangle inequality true for a point and a set?**

So the thing is that I am not sure of the **above step**, Can someone tell me if I am right?, and If I am not, Can someone help me to fix it?

Thanks a lot in advance

**NOTE**: $$d(x,A)=inf\{d(x,y):y \in A\}$$

Comment: Do you know under continuous map preimage of an open set is an open set?(This can give you a one line proof of your problem)

Comment: Yes :) I know that

Comment: Nice! Can you write your set as preimage of an open set under some continuous map?

Comment: mmm I may be, I think I will need to use the metric right?

Comment: I've added an answer,you can check it.

Comment: @BolzWeier I've edited my post :)

Answer (score 3):

**Another Approach:** First note that If $A$ is a non empty subset of a metric space $(X,d)$ then the function $f: X \to \mathbb R$ given by $f(x)=d(x,A)$ is uniformly continuous.

Because $$| f(x) - f(y) | = | d(x,A) - d(y,A) | \leq d(x,y)$$.

This means that $f$ is uniformly continuous (use $\delta = \epsilon$ in any point).

Further note that $A_\epsilon= f^{-1}( -\infty,\epsilon)$.

Comment: one doubt, how do you know that it should be uniformly continous?, is because you dont have any compactness in the hypotheses :)

Comment: Which is the inverse of the function "distance" or "metric"?

Comment: It just follows by definition of uniform continuity,you don't need any compactness here.I've added more details,it should fix your doubts.

Comment: Well is because we haven't seen in a general metric space, what uniformly continous means :)

Comment: I've edited my post :), Can you give me your verification please ?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you do not know that $d(x,A)<\varepsilon/2$. Try this: pick $x\in A$ with $d(x,A)=\varepsilon_2<\varepsilon$. Let $0<\varepsilon_1<\varepsilon-\varepsilon_2$. Now try the ball centered at $x$ of radius $\varepsilon_1$.

Comment: give just a while to think of it :)

Comment: What did you edit?, :) thanks

Comment: In the first sentence, I changed $d(z,A)$ to $d(x,A)$.

Comment: I've edited my post with the above idea, Can you check it out please?, and hoe do I perform the triangle inequality whith a set ?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. This is because the triangle inequality holds for all members of the set: $$d(z,A)=\inf_{y\in A} d(z,y)\leq\inf_{y\in A}(d(z,x)+d(x,y))=d(z,x)+\inf_{y\in A}d(x,y)=d(z,x)+d(x,A).$$

Comment: Then what I posted is correct?

Comment: Yes, as long as $\varepsilon_1=\varepsilon-d(x,A)$, and not $\varepsilon$ as stated in your third paragraph.

Comment: RIgth :), let me edited :)

Comment: So, we are done right?

Answer (score 1):

**Yet Another Approach:** We show that $\displaystyle A_\epsilon=\bigcup_{a\in A}B_\epsilon(a)$.

Let $a\in A$. If $x\in B_{\epsilon}(a)$, then
$$d(x,A)\leq d(x,a)<\epsilon.$$
Therefore, $B_\epsilon(a)\subset A_\epsilon$, so $\displaystyle \bigcup_{a\in A}B_\epsilon(a)\subset A_\epsilon$.

Conversely, suppose $\displaystyle x\in\left(\bigcup_{a\in A}B_\epsilon(a)\right)^c=\bigcap_{a\in A}B_\epsilon(a)^c$. Then, for every $a\in A$, $d(x,a)\geq\epsilon$. Hence,
$$d(x,A)=\inf\{d(x,a)\mid a\in A\}\geq \epsilon.$$
Therefore, $\displaystyle \left(\bigcup_{a\in A}B_\epsilon(a)\right)^c\subset A_\epsilon^c$, so we're done.

Comment: Thanks a lot, let me check it, If I have a doubt or some question, can I let you know?, maybe I delay a little bit :), because I have a conference :)